# How can energy be conserved while state transition is of uncertainty?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Suppose there is a particle A with spin pointing parallel to magnetic field. Particle A is perturbed by particle B and A's spin is no longer in original state. This means A may emit a photon and go back to stable state. However, the energy of this photon is related to magnetic field which means the energy particle B passes to A is uncertain until we detect the photon and its value is and only is determined by magnetic field and spin.

Answer (score -1):

The results of your measurements will always be consistent with energy conservation.